# XQuery get distinct values

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

Im new to XQuery and are trying to learn how to use it with BaseX.

I have this xml containing multiple elements of **program**:

```
<program id="4565">
        <name>Musiken i P3</name>
        <url>http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4565</url>
        <editor>Anna-Karin Larsson</editor>
        <channel>164</channel>
        <category>5</category>
</program>
```

So far i have understod that i can get the distinct values of for example editor like such:

```
let $vals := $sr/sr/programs/program/editor
let $uniqe-items := distinct-values($vals)

for $vals in $uniqe-items
    order by $vals
    return <li>{string($vals)}</li>
```

However when i do this I only get the editors name and I can't understand how i also check something like this:

```
 let $vals := $sr/sr/programs/program/editor
 let $uniqe-items := distinct-values($vals)

 for $vals in $uniqe-items
     where $vals/channel = "132"
     order by $vals
     return <li>{string($vals)}</li>
```

I was thinking that i could do something like `$vals/../channel` to get back to the channel attribute but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Is it XBase or BaseX?

Comment: @ChristianGrün My bad, BaseX is correct

Comment: I still need to understand what you would like to do with the distinct results. For example, if 2 of 3 programs with `Anna-Karin Larsson` have the channel 132, how should the result look like? It could help if you added a full input example (possibly minimized, i.e. without elements that do not contribute to the understanding, but with more than 1 program element) and the expected result to your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good to see that Yitzhak Khabinsky could help.

Comment: @ChristianGrün I'm sorry i was in a bit of a rush with this so forgot your comment. Thanks alot for your time and help. I will definitly follow this with the next question i have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution. I am using BaseX 9.5

The `distinct-values()` gives a sequence of strings: Anna-Karin Larsson, Anna Karenina, not the XML elements.

It is possible to eliminate `where` clause completely by using XPath predicate in the `for` clause:

```
for $vals in distinct-values(./programs/program[channel = "132"]/editor)
```

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare context item := document {
<programs>
    <program id="4565">
        <name>Musiken i P3</name>
        <url>http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4565</url>
        <editor>Anna-Karin Larsson</editor>
        <channel>164</channel>
        <category>5</category>
    </program>
    <program id="4770">
        <name>Musiken i P3</name>
        <url>http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4565</url>
        <editor>Anna Karenina</editor>
        <channel>132</channel>
        <category>55</category>
    </program>
</programs>  
};

<ul>
{
  for $vals in distinct-values(./programs/program[channel = "132"]/editor)
  (:where ./programs/program[editor = $vals]/channel = "132":)
  order by $vals
  return <li>{data($vals)}</li>
}
</ul>
```

**Output**

```
<ul>
  <li>Anna Karenina</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @forsb, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.